# Is there a good method to draw a trend line?

Tags: r, plot, trendline

I have a data frame called `df` including:
column `b` is the years :

```
(2015  , 2016  , 2017  , 2018  , 2019, 2020) -> b
```

column `values` include :

```
(0.1239, 0.1147, 0.1151, 0.1195, 0.1143, 0.0856) -> values
```

I want to draw a trend line (straight line) of column values (values) by column b (years), but I can't. Below are four different methods that I tried :

The red line in the attached file is the one that I need:

[image: The red trend line]

### Method 1

```
plot(b, values,
xlab= "Year", ylab = "Values (%)", main="Profit on equity", pch=19, type="line")
grid()
box()
```

**Result:**
[image: Value_1: a line]

It is a line but not a trend line (straight line)

### Method 2:

```
plot(b~values,
     xlab= "Year", ylab = "Value (%)", main="Profit on equity", pch=19)
abline(lm(b~means))
grid()
```

**Result:**
[image: Value_2: trendline with different directions].

The result shows the columns it is opposite to method 1. I don't know how to judge its trend as it is not clear.

### Method 3

```
plot(values~b,
     xlab= "Year", ylab = "Value (%)", main=" Profit on equity", pch=19)
abline(lm(values~b))
grid()
```

**Result:**
[image: Value_3: dots and no line].

This shows dots and no trend line or line created

### Method 4

```
ggplot(df, aes(b, values)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_abline()
```

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(b, values)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = values ~ b)
```

**Results:**
[image: Value_4: dots and no line].

This shows dots and no line or straight line created

### Conclusion

I can't create a trend line as I wanted even though I have tried different ways.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Note: In practice, it is hard to recognise the trend of data as It may up and down therefore the trend line helps me make a judgement of data trend.

I look forward to receiving your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.

```
plot(dat[c('b', 'values')], type='l', 
     main='Profit on equity', xlab='Year', ylab='Values (%)')
grid()
abline(lm(values ~ b, dat), col=2, lwd=2)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(b = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), values = c(0.1239, 
0.1147, 0.1151, 0.1195, 0.1143, 0.0856)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your codes. It is extremely helpful. Is it possible to plot only the red line? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @BennyVan Try changing to `type='n'`. For `abline` to work the plot must already exist and type `'n'` means `'no plot'` (it opens a blank plot area of the appropriate size with nothing on it).

Comment: Yes, thank Rui Barradas. It works well. this is an advanced code that you gave and I have learned a lot from this. 
Once again, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
plot(b, values, xlab= "Year", ylab = "Values (%)", main="Profit on equity", pch=19)
abline(lm(values~b))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but on my computer, the straight line does not appear. The result I got was only dots.  The warning is: " In abline(lm(values~b): only using the first two of 6 regression coefficients". Could you relook at this?

Comment: I did the code again and it works. Thanks for your support again. I highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `ggplot2` way.

- The line plot of the data is straightforward;
- The formula argument inherits the `x` and `y` aesthetics. Compare to your method 4.

```r
c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020) -> b 
c(0.1239, 0.1147, 0.1151, 0.1195, 0.1143, 0.0856) -> values
dat <- data.frame(b, values)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(b, values)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Values (%)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

To put the plot title in the middle of the plot, the `theme_bw` must come before setting `theme(plot.title = .)`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(b, values)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 1.5) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Values (%)") +
  ggtitle("Return on Equity") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for coding this method. I have learned a lot from this code. One important point is that the geom_smooth(formular= y~x, method =lm...,  in the instruction, they said (method = "lm") with lm in the bracket. But here, we don't use it and it works. I will use this syntax to apply to my project with more than 30 variables like this. 
I highly appreciate your support.

Comment: @BennyVan The method can be `"lm"` or `lm`. I generally use the not quoted version because it saves keystrokes and no other special reason. It's a good idea to try it both ways and see this behavior for yourself.

Comment: Hi. This is the code that I want to move the title into the middle of the plot. But it does not work. Can you help me with this? 

ggplot(dat, aes(b, values)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 1.5) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("ROE (%)") + 
  ggtitle("Return on Equity")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust= 0.5))+
  theme_bw()

Comment: @BennyVan Done, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas. This code really helps.  It is so magic that only a small tip can change the whole world.